# CSS background url not working with Chrome

Tags: css, url, firefox, google-chrome, background

So I have Chrome v20.xxx, and I'm trying to make the images on my blog appear like that have a drop shadow, using both CSS3 and background url. It's working great with FF, but the background image isn't showing up for Chrome. My pseudo-code is as follow:

```
<p>
    <a>
        <span class="img_wrapper">
            <img class="with-borders">
        </span>
    </a>
</p>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
img.with-borders, img.tn { 
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border: solid #777;
    border-width: 1px 2px 2px 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 15px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
span.img_wrapper {
    background: url('./images/et-image-sliderleft-shadow2.png') no-repeat left bottom, url('./images/et-image-sliderright-shadow2.png') no-repeat right bottom;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
}
```

It seems that Chrome is limiting the view of the background image by how much the wrapper spans, whereas Firefox ignores such limit and let the inner background image "overflow" the inline element, which is exactly what I want.

Please, how do I make it work for Chrome?

Thank you.

P.S.: I can paste this on jsfiddle if you prefer.

Update: screen shot: http://i.imgur.com/ISXDr.png

Update #2: here's jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gNtea/. What's weird is that it WORKS perfectly when viewing it in jsfiddle, just not on the [live site](http://tambnguyen.com/4493-chemin-vert-giacomo-miceli/). I thought it was the relative path issue, so I switched my production CSS to using absolute path, no help.

Update #3: I copied the source code of the webpage, pasted it on jsfiddle, it works. I view the page on the actual live site, it doesn't work. WTF? http://jsfiddle.net/eXYS9/

Comment: can you prepare a fiddle for that please? I know what you mean, but it's hard to debug nonetheless;)

Comment: hm, the fiddle shows no difference between firefox and chrome for me. Both show the shadows correcty. C19 for me though.

Comment: Right... I can't see why it's any different than the live site.

Comment: Any additional styles (`overflow`), changes in the markup, typos or anything else? Do you have exactly the same styles on the inspected elements?

Comment: I have a few overflows, but they have nothing to do with this; no typos, nothing crazy. And yes, I see exactly the same styles on these inspected elements. Here's the non-minified CSS (my snippet starts on 204): http://pastebin.com/DTm5Wi6W

Comment: fiddle working fine in two browsers but live site have some trouble. i think other css properties overriding this 'with-borders' properties. checkup all those.

Comment: @sam: I thought so too, so I copied the source code of the web page plus the raw CSS and then paste them on jsfiddle, everything looks good. http://jsfiddle.net/eXYS9/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS background not working with Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958507/css-background-not-working-with-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the height of image =)

```
li.current-menu-item a {
background: url("../images/bg_menu.png") repeat-x;    
height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

span.img_wrapper {
    background: url('../images/et-image-sliderleft-shadow2.png') no-repeat left bottom, url('./images/et-image-sliderright-shadow2.png') no-repeat right bottom;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
}

Use **..[two dots]** instead of one for the image url

Comment: Actually, the ./images directory is one level down from where the CSS is... in fact, Chrome is able to locate it when I inspect the elements. However, it won't display the background image if the image overflows the span element.

Comment: `./` refers to the same level and is perfectly valid.