# CSS background not working with Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background

I have the following HTML and CSS code, can you please tell me why it works on FF, IE9, jsfiddle and NOT on the live site with Google Chrome?

HTML:

```
<p>
    <a href="http://tambnguyen.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/256501557_1280.jpg">
        <span class="img_wrapper">
            <img class="tn" src="http://tambnguyen.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/256501557_1280-580x326.jpg"/>
        </span>
    </a>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
img.with-borders, img.tn { 
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border: solid #777;
    border-width: 1px 2px 2px 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 15px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
span.img_wrapper {
    background: url('http://tambnguyen.com/wp-content/themes/Polished/images/et-image-sliderleft-shadow2.png') no-repeat left bottom, url('http://tambnguyen.com/wp-content/themes/Polished/images/et-image-sliderright-shadow2.png') no-repeat right bottom;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
}
img.with-borders:hover, img.tn:hover, img.post_img:hover, div.related_post_thumb:hover  { 
    border-color: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.80;
}
```

The jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/gNtea/, and the live site is here http://tambnguyen.com/4493-chemin-vert-giacomo-miceli/

Thank you!​

Comment: Sorry, can you provide screenshots? Looking in JFiddle with IE9 and Chrome, they are identical.

Comment: For one thing, transitions don't work with `filter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add `display: inline-block;` to the img_wrapper, like:

```
span.img_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('http://tambnguyen.com/wp-content/themes/Polished/images/et-image-sliderleft-shadow2.png') no-repeat left bottom, url('http://tambnguyen.com/wp-content/themes/Polished/images/et-image-sliderright-shadow2.png') no-repeat right bottom;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
}
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!!! I've been at this for days. Even posted the same question on here a few nights ago without any luck. You are my hero!

Comment: Btw, why does it not work on a live site, but it works on jsfiddle?

Comment: @aZn137, I provided an answer that addresses why it works on jsFiddle. To clarify, the answer provided by Chris Mohr is not wrong, just different.

Answer (score 2):

I visited both the **jsFiddle** link and the **live website** in Chrome that is currently using the `display:inline-block;` fix to allow the corner background images to be seen.

Currently, I can see that there is a large gap after the background shadow images end and before the Social Buttons start. This is because of `inline-block` being used.

Instead, omit using `display:inline-block;` (after reading this *entire* answer) and just define all padding values for `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`.

That said and because you are floating objects in your live webpage, give `padding-right` a value of `1px`.

Either of these two methods will work.

**Method 1 - Shorthand padding (top, right, bottom, left):**

```
padding: 0 1px 18px 0;
```

**Method 2 - Specifying missing `padding-right` value:**

```
padding-bottom: 18px;
padding-right: 1px;
```

Now you can view the Poster Image with the background images without changing the layout of the webpage... and that large gap is gone too.

But this answer is not complete until I explain why it works on jsFiddle but not the live website. The simple answer is jsFiddle is a sandbox and is not perfect. This can be considered a jsFiddle bug.

I will illustrate this jsFiddle bug with your current fix and a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4yek/) of your complete HTML page that was copied and pasted right into the HTML panel. Nothing was changed.

Now, using Chrome developer tools (*hit F12 on the keyboard*), you can then use **Inspect Element** for the image... once shown in the Elements Tab, you'll be in the area to click on the `span` tag that's right above.

Now comes the fun part, you can disable the style for the `display:inline-block;` by removing the **checkmark** (via Styles when expanded in right panel) and you will see a slight pixel shift in Chrome for those .png images but to be sure, they are still visible!

The bottom line: Consider **jsFiddle** an excellent tool but the Chrome Browser, or ***any browser***, should be the sole interface when testing a page for production work. It should have the final say without a go-between.

---

**Reference Photo 1:** `display:inline-block`
[image: Layout is affected with gap.]

---

**Reference Photo 2:** `padding-right: 1px;`
[image: Layout is not affected.]

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough explanation. Yes, I do realize I need to test with all real browsers for production code. jsFiddle was only a tool for me to paste the code and enable anyone else who wanted to change it on the fly. I was able to confirm that adding `padding-right:1px;` also works, but I'm not sure how that fixes my original problem of the <span> element not being shown. Will you please elaborate?

Comment: Btw, I wanted to "share" box to be a bit further down because those buttons are for sharing the entire post, not just the images themselves. As part of a movement to clean up the web, as well as raising privacy concerns, I don't have script-driven social buttons. My buttons are pure HTML and CSS, with a tad of jQuery for popup. They work even if JS is disabled :)

Comment: Reference comment: *"jsFiddle was only a tool for me to paste the code and enable anyone else who wanted to change it on the fly"*. My answer is actually based on your Question content *"tell me why it works on FF, IE9, jsfiddle"*. That said, it appears that your webpage use of floating objects `right` works differently in Chrome when not **sandboxed**, hence use of `padding-right:1px;` setting.

Comment: Reference comment: *"Btw, I wanted to "share" box to be a bit further down"*. Using `padding-right:1px;` would be the correct method and then additional CSS rule to set the social buttons lower is required. Right now, the social buttons are at the visual location from something else affecting it. That said, the location is correct per your goal but the method on how it got there isn't IMHO.

Comment: Gotcha. So it all boils down to how different engines render differently, and in this case Webkit is the one that's not tolerating, no?

Comment: I only spent time with jsFiddle and Chrome to discover that jsFiddle handle things differently... and at that time it was the "then current" release of both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the height of image =)

```
li.current-menu-item a {
background: url("../images/bg_menu.png") repeat-x;    
height: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I add the same problem with Chrome but my fix was bizarre

This was my original CSS code in the body wrapper

```
background-image: url(../../img/layout/bgOutside-rtl.jpg);
```

But the image repeated, which was not what I wanted. I tried the solutions offered elsewhere but in most cases this made things worse.

I added this

```
background-image: url(../../img/layout/bgOutside-rtl.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

PHPStorm suggested that this was a better alternative

```
background: url(../../img/layout/bgOutside-rtl.jpg) no-repeat;
```

Which seemed logical but it didnt work. Chrome seemed to take that as an instruction not to display any image at all.

The only way I got this to work was to go back to

```
background-image: url(../../img/layout/bgOutside-rtl.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Go figure. It worked and all browsers rendered the page correctly.

Even more odd was the fact that this issue didnt occur when writing the code in Linux, it only happens when using the Windows version of Chrome ...